# Pyramid problem - find the height of the pyramid by given edges and a side from the base

Tags: solid-geometry

The base of a pyramid is a right triangle with the longest side = 12cm. All non base edges are also equal to 12cm. And how can I find the height of the pyramid?

Comment: You have an equilateral triangle, so all angles are 60 and $\sin(60) = \text{???}$.

Comment: I don't think this has enough information to solve. If it's a 45-45-90 right triangle, then the height will be smaller than if it is a say 1-89-90 right triangle.

Comment: @Peter Woolfitt - there is enough information - for the arbitrary points of a right triangle for a given hypotonusa lie on a circle of which the hypothenusa is the diameter...

Comment: @johannesvalks Ah yes, I see now. Thanks for your excellent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Thales' theorem.

You can select the points

$$
A = (-6,0,0), B = (+6,0,0),
$$

to form the longest side of the base triangle. The other point $C$ lies on a circle of which $AB$ is the diameter, as

$$
y^2 + \big[ 6 - x \big]^2 + y^2 + \big[ 6 + x \big]^2 = 144,
$$

so

$$
x^2 + y^2 = 36
$$

The top point $T$ is given by $(0,0,z)$ and it is clear that

$$
|AT| = |BT| = |CT|
$$

as $A$, $B$ and $C$ lie on the same circle, as $|AT| = |BT| = |AB|$, we obtain

$$
z = 6 \sqrt{3}
$$

[image: Thales' Theorem]

Comment: The realization that the top point is over the origin is key.  Well  done.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Thanks - the image above is also the top view where $O$ and the top $T$ are the same as seen from above...